# Switching last two char in a string

Tags: java

Learning java as my first language and I found a solution for the problem at codingbat but I don't understand why my solution doesn't work and would love your help.

> Given a string of any length, return a new string where the last 2
>   chars, if present, are swapped, so "coding" yields "codign".
>
> lastTwo("coding") → "codign"
>  lastTwo("cat") → "cta"
>   lastTwo("ab") → "ba"

This is my not working code:

```
public String lastTwo(String str) {

  int strLength = str.length();
  String last = str.substring(strLength-1,strLength);
  String bLast = str.substring(strLength-2,strLength-1);

  if(strLength<2)
  return str;
  return str.substring(0, strLength-2)+last+bLast; 
}
```

This are the errors and I cant figure out why:

> lastTwo("a")
>   →
> "Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String
>   index out of range: -1 (line number:5)"
>     lastTwo("")
>   →
> "Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String
>   index out of range: -1 (line number:4)"

It seems there is a problem when input is less than 2 chars but I can't figure out why. To me, the if logic looks okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move if condition up in the method as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(lastTwo("coding"));
    System.out.println(lastTwo("cat"));
    System.out.println(lastTwo("ab"));
    System.out.println(lastTwo("a"));
}
public static String lastTwo(String str) {

    int strLength = str.length();
    if(strLength<2)
        return str;

    String last = str.substring(strLength-1,strLength);
    String bLast = str.substring(strLength-2,strLength-1);
    return str.substring(0, strLength-2)+last+bLast;
}
```

This will print:

> codign
>   cta
>   ba
>   a

In the method if length of `str` is less than 2 (e.g. 1) in that case it will be returned else it will compute `last` and `blast` and then perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

When the input is is 1 char, `strLength-2` is `-1`. The method`substring` throws the error because such index doesn't exist. (The same applies to 0 char and `strLength-1`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this verification on top

```
if(strLength<2)
  return str;
```

When you have this code, if the string is "", it is trying to get the substring between positions -1,0 and -2,-1. You can't get the substring in a position lower than 0.

```
int strLength = str.length();
String last = str.substring(strLength-1,strLength);
String bLast = str.substring(strLength-2,strLength-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution is to take the start-of-string and

append the last-char and then

append the before-last-char:

```
public static String lastTwo(String str) {
    if (str.length()<2){
        return str;
    } else{
        return str.substring(0, str.length() - 2) + 
                str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + 
                str.charAt(str.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, why ?. its compiled and tested. s="cat" returns "cta" , s="coding" returns "codign".

Answer (score 0):

```
public String lastTwo(String str) {
    if(str != null ) {
        int strLength = str.length();
        if (strLength < 2)
            return str;
        String last = str.substring(strLength-1,strLength);
        String bLast = str.substring(strLength-2,strLength-1);
        return str.substring(0, strLength-2)+last+bLast; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Problem in your code is `String bLast = str.substring(strLength-2,strLength-1);`
when strLength = 1 and you subtract by 2 and your index will be -1, hence `IndexOutOfboundException` occure.
Use above code your problem solved.

Comment: Is it just me, or does returning `null` makes no sense?

Answer (score 0):

One of the overloads for substring can take the starting index , it figures out the last index. So the following should give you the last two chars:

```
str.substring(java.lang.Math.max(0,str.length()-2))
```